# Uploading files in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have a project based on codeignitor , im facing a problem with uploading forms i cant attach more than one files i have an  upload fields to attach user profile picture im trying to duplacate the filed to attach two or more files with no chance .

note i do all the changes in MVC files to the dublicated fields .

Here is the field code

```
<?php 
                    if(isset($image)) 
                        echo "<div class='form-group has-error' >";
                    else     
                        echo "<div class='form-group' >";
                ?>
                    <label for="qr" class="col-sm-2 control-label col-xs-8 col-md-2">
                        <?=$this->lang->line("student_passport_pic")?>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control"  id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" disabled />  
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-success form-control">
                            <span class="fa fa-repeat"></span>
                            <span><?=$this->lang->line("upload")?></span>
                            <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name="image" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <span class="col-sm-4 control-label col-xs-6 col-md-4">

                        <?php if(isset($image)) echo $image; ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

please advice i need to upload too many files .

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple images from the same field. Make the input field name as an array.

For Ex : The first upload field should be like below

```
<input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name="image[]"/>
```

Then, the input field which you are generating should also be of the same name

```
<input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name="image[]"/>
```

and then in the controller where you are taking the POST value, you can take the values of the field using the **$this->input->post('image')** which will give you all the image names.

Comment: this is to attach more than one file in the same field . what i need is to add another field to another filed in database .

Comment: So you want to show the user another upload button ? I didn't got your question clearly.

Comment: yes and i do duplicate the field with no chance it is not attaching the file to the server and also to the DB i dont know why maybe i have to use another field to do it ??